# pull json data from a json file on a .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a text box and a button. On the button . click function the name appears but I want  id (that the user enters  into the text box for the corresponding name to appear)

this is a snip from the json:

```
{"user":[{"ID" : "001","name": "Zara Ali"}]}
```

This is the button/text ( that i have inside an alert div because i think it looks cool in my page and works with the .click)

```
<div class="alert alert-info"> 
  <input type="text" id="userName" value> 
  <button type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Login</button>
</div>
```

and this is the js i have used for the .click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loginbtn").click(function(event){
    $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
      $('#details').html('<p> Name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
    });
  });           
});
```

the result is going inside:

```
<div id = "details">

</div>
```

Comment: Are you returning more than one user? If not why the array instead of returning just the user object?

Comment: `console.log(jd)`. you don't have `jd.name`, you have `jd[0].name`. an object containing an array of objects...

Comment: try this @Mac  `$.grep( [{"ID" : "001","name": "Zara Ali"}], function( n, i ) {
  return n.ID==='001';
});`

Comment: @Mac try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/08oedewb/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginbtn").click(function(event){
       $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
          var id = $('#userName').val();
          for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) {
            if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {
              $('#details').html('<p> Name: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>');
            }
          }
       });
    });
 });
```

Comment: Hi jcubic - thank you very much for your answer but this did not work for me - would there be anything I would have to change in my json maybe?

Comment: @LMac forget about `val()` try now.

Comment: @LMac If it solve your problem don't forget to mark the answer.